# azure trace log has gaps

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We're using trace logging extensively in our azure application, but occasionally we see gaps in the logs up to 90m or so.

Why would this be, and how do I go about diagnosing?  This is fairly important because we're using the data in the WADLogsTable as source data for an alert system.

**Update**: Sorry for the delay.  My configuration is as follows:

```
   <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
            <listeners>
                <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                    name="AzureDiagnostics">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

The rest of the configuration is done programmatically:

public static void ConfigureDiagnosticMonitor(TimeSpan? scheduledTransferPeriod)
    {
        TimeSpan stp = scheduledTransferPeriod ?? DefaultScheduledTransferPeriod;

```
    var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
    config.OverallQuotaInMB = 8192;

    // configure Windows Event Log monitoring.
    config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
    config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Warning;
    config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = stp;

    // configure Diagnostic infrastructure logs
    config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;
    config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.BufferQuotaInMB = 100;
    config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = stp;

    // configure Logs
    config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
    config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 100;
    config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = stp;

    // configure Directories
    config.Directories.DataSources.Add(AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.GetLogDirectory());
    config.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = stp;

    DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your diagnostics configuration?

Comment: @Igorek yep - I updated the question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the local diagnostic storage fills up before Azure is able to purge some data form it.

Try reducing the overall quota to under 4gigs and all the other quotas underneath to match so that they fall under the total.  Azure by default allocates only 4gigs to the whole diagnostics space and you want to be under that amount so that to give diagnostic agent some time to trim the data.